# "`self` has an anonymous lifetime `'_` but it needs to satisfy a `'static` lifetime requirement" when access self. fields of struct from thread

Tags: rust

I implemented struct, which use some threads inside it. When I try to use self. inside thread, I got an error:

```
error[E0759]: `self` has an anonymous lifetime `'_` but it needs to satisfy a `'static` lifetime requirement
   --> src/main.rs:37:23
    |
36  |       fn spawn_write_thread(&mut self) -> thread::JoinHandle<()> {
    |                             --------- this data with an anonymous lifetime `'_`...
37  |           thread::spawn(move || {
    |  _______________________^
38  | |             let val = self.receiver.recv().unwrap();
39  | |             self.push(val);
40  | |             thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(10));
41  | |         })
    | |_________^ ...is used here...
    |
note: ...and is required to live as long as `'static` here
   --> src/main.rs:37:9
    |
37  |         thread::spawn(move || {
    |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: `'static` lifetime requirement introduced by this bound
```

This is my code:

```
use std::thread;
use std::sync::mpsc;
use std::time::Duration;
use rand::Rng;

struct Test {
    data: Vec<u8>,
    sender: mpsc::Sender<u8>, 
    receiver: mpsc::Receiver<u8>,
}

impl Test {
    pub fn new(
        sender: mpsc::Sender<u8>, 
        receiver: mpsc::Receiver<u8>
    ) -> Self {
        Self {
            data: vec![],
            sender,
            receiver,
        }
    }
    pub fn push(&mut self, item: u8) {
        self.data.push(item);
    }

    fn spawn_read_thread(&mut self) -> thread::JoinHandle<()> {
        thread::spawn(move || {
            let val = rand::thread_rng().gen();
            self.sender.send(val).unwrap();
            thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(10));
        })
    }

    fn spawn_write_thread(&mut self) -> thread::JoinHandle<()> {
        thread::spawn(move || {
            let val = self.receiver.recv().unwrap();
            self.push(val);
            thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(10));
        })
    }

    pub fn output(&mut self) {
        self.spawn_read_thread();
        self.spawn_write_thread();
    
        for _ in 0..20 {
            println!("{:?}", self.data);
            thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(100));
        }
    }
}

fn main () {
    let (sender, receiver) = mpsc::channel();
    let test = Test::new(sender.clone(), receiver);
    test.output();
}
```

This is [sandbox implementation](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=dd316ed4580e040be248e898b32bc012).

I tried to use Arc + Mutex on specific `self.` fields/methods, but this didn't help.

Could you explain, how to use `self` references inside thread to access struct's fields/methods ?

Comment: Please always post the full error from `cargo check`.

Comment: Please show us your attempt with `Arc`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e3d9c8ba18a691ee2686a9bbee3bed05

Comment: @ChayimFriedman added full error

Comment: You cannot take the method `push()` and put it into an `Arc`. The compiler is telling you that.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I understand this. Also I cannot put `data` property into the `Arc`. Could you advice how to fix this ?

Comment: Put the `data` property into `Arc`. This is the proper way to do that. Other than that, there are multiple ways to use data in threads, but we cannot tell more without an explanation of the use-case and constraints.

Comment: Wrap it in `Mutex`: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8c0678b9c4d91b7945812fc1e6e787b5

Comment: Your programming style in general is very C++ heavy. The concept of self-referencial data structures is very normal in C++, but almost impossible in Rust. I have the feeling that you will encounter some more of these hurdles until your brain manages to un-learn previous programming patterns and forms new ones. I've been there, it takes a while and can be frustrating at times. Don't give up, it's worth it. Rust programming patterns are completely different than other languages, but very clean in the end (in my experience)

Comment: Further, understanding programming principles like ownership chains will help you write better code in other languages, as well. In my experience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Rust, every object has to be *owned* by exactly one owner. Then, you can *borrow* references to that object, but it must be **known** to the one borrowing how long the object lives. Dangling references (references that refer to an object that doesn't exist any more) are undefined behaviour, and by definition, *Rust does not have any undefined behaviour* as long as you don't use `unsafe`.

Sadly, in your case, the owning context of the `test` object (which I'll refer to as `self` from now on) is on a different *thread* than the context holding the reference (`self.sender.send()` actually creates a reference to `self.sender` and by extension to `self`). But the compiler does not know how long the thread lives, or if the `test` object outlives the reference. That's why it throws an error.

If you look at the error message:

```
`self` has an anonymous lifetime `'_` but it needs to satisfy a `'static` lifetime requirement
```

It says that in order to use a reference in a thread, the reference has to be `'static`, meaning, the object reference needs to live for the entire duration of the program. (`'static` means actually something slightly different, but in the context of this example, that's what it means).

---

I'd like to point you to a solution in the way of "change those two lines and then it's fixed"; sadly, I don't think such a solution exists.

Yes, it's suggested in the comments to use `Arc<Mutex>`, which does eliminate the lifetime problem by introducing reference counters, so that the thread itself can keep the objects alive and not just borrow them. But I feel like those are just hotfixes for a more underlying architectural proble.

---

The actual, underlying problem, is that your code shows no clear concept of ownership trees. That is not a problem in other languages, and that's why it's a little hard to cope with it at the beginning.

Let me demonstrate what I mean. Remember, in Rust it must always be clear where a variable is owned and how long it lives:

- `main` owns the `Test` object
- `Test` object owns `sender` and `receiver`
- in a way, conceptually, `Test` owns the threads, because it spawns them
- the threads interact with the `sender` and `receiver` mutably, so the threads in a way need to own the `sender` and `receiver` as well
- the threads use the `Test` object mutably, so in a way, the threads also need to own the `Test` object

It's just a big mess of everyone-owns-everyone, which is probably how you would implement it in C++ and smart pointers, or even raw pointers. In Rust, the chain of ownership has to be much more specific.

---

So let's ask ourselves, who actually needs to own what?

That's the part where I get a little speculative, because your description is not sufficient to understand the underlying usecase. I will base my assumptions on the code you posted.

- Does `main` need to own the `Test` object?

  - Yes, someone has to. Otherwise nobody would own the `Test` object.
- Does `Test` need to own `sender` and `receiver`?

  - That's the first point where I'd disagree with your code. Apart of when it spawns the threads, the `Test` object never uses `sender` and `receiver` again. So I'd argue that the real owners of those should be the threads instead.
- Does `Test` need to own the threads?

  - I'd argue "yes", and I'd even say it doesn't own them enough yet. You spawn the threads and then drop the `JoinHandle`s immediately. I'd keep the `JoinHandle`s and make sure to dispose of the threads properly when the `Test` object gets destroyed.
- Do the threads need to own the `sender` and `receiver`?

  - Yes, definitely. They are the only context that actually interacts with those.
- Do the threads need to own the `Test` object?

  - that one is the most tricky one, because this one creates a circular ownership chain. The `Test` object owns the threads, and the threads own the `Test` object because they need to call `push()`. It's a dataflow problem, which is a quite common problem that causes circular ownership problems. There are two ways to solve that in Rust, usually:

    - `channel`s: Break the need of carrying the `self` object over by changing the `callback` pattern to a `channel` pattern. `callback` patterns in general are discouraged in Rust, due to the ownership problems you just encountered. This is one of the most common programming pattern conversions when porting C++ code to Rust, as you can pass the `sender` part of a channel to a thread without having to pass its receiver into it.
    - Reference counters, e.g. `Arc<Mutex<>>`. In this case, as you *want* to actually change the data from the thread and not just pass events into a pipe, I think this is the pattern I'd go for.

---

With all those changes applied, this is kind of the direction I would go:

```rust
use rand::Rng;
use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicBool, Ordering};
use std::sync::{mpsc, Arc, Mutex};
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;

struct Test {
    data: Arc<Mutex<Vec<u8>>>,
    read_thread: Option<thread::JoinHandle<()>>,
    write_thread: Option<thread::JoinHandle<()>>,
    sender_should_stop: Arc<AtomicBool>,
}

impl Test {
    pub fn new(sender: mpsc::Sender<u8>, receiver: mpsc::Receiver<u8>) -> Self {
        let data = Arc::new(Mutex::new(vec![]));
        let sender_should_stop = Arc::new(AtomicBool::new(false));

        let read_thread = Some(Test::spawn_read_thread(sender, sender_should_stop.clone()));
        let write_thread = Some(Test::spawn_write_thread(receiver, data.clone()));

        Self {
            data,
            read_thread,
            write_thread,
            sender_should_stop,
        }
    }

    fn spawn_read_thread(
        sender: mpsc::Sender<u8>,
        should_stop: Arc<AtomicBool>,
    ) -> thread::JoinHandle<()> {
        println!("Spawning sender ...");
        thread::spawn(move || loop {
            let val = rand::thread_rng().gen();
            if let Err(_) = sender.send(val) {
                println!("Channel got closed. Stopping sender ...");
                break;
            }
            thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(1000));

            // Stop sender if signalled
            if should_stop.load(Ordering::Acquire) {
                println!("Sender received the signal to stop. Stopping sender ...");
                break;
            };
        })
    }

    fn spawn_write_thread(
        receiver: mpsc::Receiver<u8>,
        data: Arc<Mutex<Vec<u8>>>,
    ) -> thread::JoinHandle<()> {
        println!("Spawning receiver ...");
        thread::spawn(move || loop {
            let val = match receiver.recv() {
                Ok(val) => val,
                Err(_) => {
                    println!("Channel got closed. Stopping receiver ...");
                    break;
                }
            };

            data.lock().unwrap().push(val);
        })
    }

    pub fn output(&self) {
        for _ in 0..20 {
            println!("{:?}", self.data.lock().unwrap());
            thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(333));
        }
    }
}

impl Drop for Test {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        // Signal the sender to stop.
        println!("Signalling sender to stop ...");
        self.sender_should_stop.store(true, Ordering::Release);

        // Wait for the sender to finish
        std::mem::take(&mut self.read_thread)
            .unwrap()
            .join()
            .unwrap();
        println!("Sender stopped.");

        // Now that the sender is finished and dropped its part of the channel,
        // the receiver will finish as well
        std::mem::take(&mut self.write_thread)
            .unwrap()
            .join()
            .unwrap();
        println!("Receiver stopped.");
    }
}

fn main() {
    let (sender, receiver) = mpsc::channel();
    let test = Test::new(sender, receiver);
    test.output();
}
```

```
Spawning sender ...
Spawning receiver ...
[]
[82]
[82]
[82]
[82, 79]
[82, 79]
[82, 79]
[82, 79, 8]
[82, 79, 8]
[82, 79, 8]
[82, 79, 8, 114]
[82, 79, 8, 114]
[82, 79, 8, 114]
[82, 79, 8, 114, 194]
[82, 79, 8, 114, 194]
[82, 79, 8, 114, 194]
[82, 79, 8, 114, 194, 210]
[82, 79, 8, 114, 194, 210]
[82, 79, 8, 114, 194, 210]
[82, 79, 8, 114, 194, 210, 231]
Signalling sender to stop ...
Sender received the signal to stop. Stopping sender ...
Channel got closed. Stopping receiver ...
Sender stopped.
Receiver stopped.
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ceb520408bb430a2af99fd7ee5f1dc2d)

---

Now you can clearly see the ownership tree:

- `data`: owned by `Arc`
- `sender_should_stop`: owned by `Arc`
- `main`

  - `test`

    - `data`: ->`Arc`
    - `sender_should_stop`: ->`Arc`
    - `read_thread`

      - `sender`
      - `should_stop`: ->`Arc`
    - `write_thread`

      - `receiver`
      - `data`: ->`Arc`

---

*Annotation:* I know that nobody actually owns a thread, it's just a handle and the thread can live without it. I just conceptually think of a thread being owned by the `JoinHandle` because usually, the `JoinHandle` is used for error propagation.

Comment: thank you for detailed explanation ! from my side: I am working on TCP client. I need to take packets in same order as they come from server (to be possible to decrypt them), so I decided to use Arc<Mutex<VecDeque<Vec<u8>>>> for this purpose. I have 3 threads: one for read from server and put packets into input_queue, one for handle packets and put results into output_queue and one for write results from output_queue to the server. Unfortunately, I cannot create minimal example using real code (I remember somebody in comments asked for minimal code). So tried to reproduce common problem.

Comment: @SergioIvanuzzo Yah, I figured. Hot tip: if you work with networking, try to get into `async` programming as soon as possible. The `tokio` library is an excellent asynchronous networking and runtime library. I can wholeheartedly advise you to read [this tutorial](https://tokio.rs/tokio/tutorial) about it.